# How can I move Exchange items to a PST using PowerShell?

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell

We have a mailbox that receives status emails that we need to keep essentially for ever, and they contain potentially large attachments. I need to be able to move these messages to a PST on a regular (daily or weekly) basis so want to automate this.

At the moment I am using a `MailboxExportRequest` to get them into a PST:

```
New-MailboxExportRequest -ContentFilter {(Received -ge '01/01/2013') -and (Received -lt '01/02/2013')} -Mailbox "MonitorMailbox" -FilePath "\\Server\backup\EmailLog\MonitorMailbox 2013-01.pst"
```

And I follow this with a `SearchMailbox -DeleteContent`:

```
Get-Mailbox -Identity "MonitorMailbox" | Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery "Received:01/01/2013..01/02/2013" -DeleteContent
```

The problem is that I'm having to manually update the date parameters each time in four places, and I'm worried that it's not very *transactional* (if that even makes sense in this context).

I'm trying to create a little PS script to iterate through dates by month and build a set of commands to spin through and export this information, but was wondering if there's a simpler way to "move to PST", or if I need to try and build the above statements dynamically.

---

Here's a more complete script, as I have it so far, which should export all items for the 10 days preceding the beginning of this month (to speed up testing):

```
$mailbox = "Cylindric"
$endDate = Get-Date -Day 1 "00:00:00"
$startDate = $endDate.AddDays(-10)

$month = "{0:D2}" -f [int]$startDate.Month
$year = "{0:D4}" -f [int]$startDate.Year


Write-Host -NoNewline "Exporting items between $startDate and $endDate..."
New-MailboxExportRequest -Name "EmailLog$year$month" -ContentFilter {(Received -ge $startDate) -and (Received -lt $endDate)} -Mailbox $mailbox -FilePath "\\ReadyNAS\backup\Mailboxes\EmailLog\EmailLog${year}-${month}.pst"
Write-Host "Done."


Write-Host -NoNewline "Waiting for export to complete..."
While(!(Get-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $mailbox -Name "EmailLog$year$month" -Status Completed))
{
    #Sleep for a  few minutes
    Write-Host -NoNewline "."
    Start-Sleep -s 60
}
Write-Host "Done."


Write-Host -NoNewline "Removing Export Request..."
Get-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $mailbox -Status Completed -Name "EmailLog$year$month" | Remove-MailboxExportRequest
Write-Host "Done."
```

And the output:

```
Exporting items between 05/22/2013 00:00:00 and 06/01/2013 00:00:00...
Name            Mailbox       Status
----            -------       ------
EmailLog201305  Cylindric     Queued
Done.
Waiting for export to complete..........Done.
```

This seems to be exporting a lot more than these 10 days though. The PST appears to contain ALL emails!

Comment: Have you considered creating an archive mailbox? http://exchangeserverpro.com/create-archive-mailbox-exchange-server-2010/

Comment: Enterprise feature, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Get-Date` cmdlet!

The snippet below will check what month it is, subtract 1 and export all messages to your .pst file

```
$endDate = Get-Date -Day 1 "00:00:00"
$startDate = $endDate.AddMonths(-1)
$month = "{0:D2}" -f [int]$startDate.Month

# Convert dates to short date strings
$endDate = $endDate.ToShortDateString()
$startDate = $startDate.ToShortDateString()

New-MailboxExportRequest -ContentFilter {(Received -ge $startDate) -and (Received -lt $endDate)} -Mailbox "MonitorMailbox" -FilePath "\\Server\backup\EmailLog\MonitorMailbox 2013-${month}.pst"

while(!(Get-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox "MonitorMailbox" -Status Completed))
{
    #Sleep for a  few minutes
    Start-Sleep -s 300
}
Get-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox "MonitorMailbox" -Status Completed | Remove-MailboxExportRequest

Get-Mailbox -Identity "MonitorMailbox" | Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery "Received:'${startDate}'..'${endDate}'" -DeleteContent
```

Simple run this once a month to get the last months emails archived

Comment: The `New-ExportRequest` runs asynchronously, how can I make sure the delete doesn't try to start before the export is finished?

Comment: See my added suggestion. Remember to test it before setting it up

Comment: Not sure why, but I'm always getting my entire mailbox exported. I had something like this before when using the `ContentFilter`, and I could only get it working with manual date strings as the parameters instead of variables.

Comment: Just realized why, see my updated example

Comment: For anyone having a hard time getting this to work, the content filter may need to be specified as "(Received -ge '$startDate') -and (Received -lt '$endDate')"; otherwise, it would become $null as reported in this question: http://serverfault.com/questions/591798/mailboxexportrequest-contentfilter-is-received-ne-null-when-querying-by-date

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to put this into a scheduled task, this should get what you're looking for:

```
$now=get-datetime
$fromtime=$now.addHours(-$now.hour).addMinutes(-$now.minute).addSeconds(-$now.second).addDay(-2)
$totime=$now.addHours(-$now.hour).addMinutes(-$now.minute).addSeconds(-$now.second).addDay(-1)
New-MailboxExportRequest -ContentFilter {(Received -ge $fromtime) -and (Received -lt $totime)} -Mailbox "MonitorMailbox" -FilePath "\\Server\backup\EmailLog\MonitorMailbox "+$totime.year+"-"+$totime.month+"-"+$totime.day"+".pst"
$mailQuery="Received:"+fromtime.toString("d")+".."+$totime.toString("d")
Get-Mailbox -Identity "MonitorMailbox" | Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery $mailQuery -DeleteContent
```

What it does is take advantage of Powershell's date handling functions. The `$fromtime` and `$totime` variables are first zeroed to midnight, then set to a distance of one day. We then use those variables in constructing the queries needed by the Exchange cmdlets.