# MailboxExportRequest ContentFilter is "Received -ne $null" when querying by date

Tags: exchange, powershell, exchange-2013

I am trying to export a mailbox to a PST. All email that was received before yesterday is what I am trying to export.

```
$y = ((get-date).addDays(-1)).ToShortDateString()
$exportRequest = New-MailboxExportRequest -ContentFilter {(Received -lt $y)} -mailbox userID -FilePath\\SHARED\folder\userID.pst
```

Something is not right here. I end up exporting the entire mailbox.

When I run a:

```
Get-MailboxExportRequest | Get-MailboxExportRequestStatistics | select ContentFilter
```

It says that my content filter is:

```
Received -ne $null
```

I am sure something is wrong with my syntax here, but I can't seem to get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a finicky syntax error and made worse by incorrect/unclear documentation.  Please try the following --

```
$y = ((get-date).addDays(-1)).ToShortDateString()
$exportRequest = New-MailboxExportRequest -ContentFilter "Received -lt '$y'" -mailbox userID -FilePath \\SHARED\folder\userID.pst
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error with this. I feel like I have tried nearly every possible way of doing this. I have triple checked my time format... Everything.

Comment: Well not everything.... Can you explain to my why this worked `Received -lt '$($y)'`

Comment: I can't explain it.  I just played around with it a bit and settled on `-ContentFilter "Received -lt '$y'"` as the simplest accepted syntax.  I couldn't really say why it doesn't work for you.  Your alternatively proposed method also works on my machine, but I don't know why it seems to be necessary.  More disturbingly, the official documentation flat-out doesn't work for either of us.