# ContentFilter is invalid. System.Datetime

Tags: exchange, windows-server-2012, powershell

If i run the following

```
$3MonthsBack = Get-Date (Get-Date).AddMonths(-3) -f MM/dd/yyyy
New-MailboxExportRequest -mailbox kundesenter@company.no -IncludeFolders akriv -ContentFilter{Received -lt "$3MonthsBack"} -FilePath "\\sto-cm-01\Test\$BatchName.pst" -name "$BatchName" -ExcludeDumpster
```

I get this:

```
The provided ContentFilter value is invalid. ContentFilter is invalid. The value "$3MonthsBack" could not be converted to type System.DateTime. --> The value "$3MonthsBack" could not be converted to type System.DateTime.
```

When I check the system clock it is formated 6/29/2016 and if i run $3MonthsBack it spits out 03/29/2016 (Same format?)

How do i fix this?

Comment: there is no space between argument name and parameter in -ContentFilter{Received -lt "$3MonthsBack"}   - is this a typo?

Comment: Added a space between and that didn't change the result.

Comment: Get-Date (Get-Date).AddMonths(-3) should work just fine. Is it working this way? Does it have to be in that format?

Comment: Same issue using Get-Date (Get-Date).Addmonths(-3)

Comment: What happens if you hardcode time values into code? {Received -lt "03/29/2016"}

Comment: It can't be hardcoded. I am going to run the script daily so having it hardcoded isen't an option.

But for the sake of testing. "-ContentFilter {Received -lt "03/29/2016"}" this works without an issue

Comment: I only suggested harcoding as a test option to isolate the issue :) does this work: "-ContentFilter {Received -lt (Get-Date (Get-Date).AddMonths(-3) -f MM/dd/yyyy)"  ?

Comment: Ah, Well... "-ContentFilter {Received -lt (Get-Date (Get-Date).AddMonths(-3) -f MM/dd/yyyy)}" spits back the same error

Comment: how about this one http://serverfault.com/questions/591798/mailboxexportrequest-contentfilter-is-received-ne-null-when-querying-by-date

Comment: Well shit, That worked. I'll fiddle around a bit more with it to see what works and what doesn't work and update the post.

Answer (score 1):

After @sergei help, I have now found out how to solve it.

With New-Mailboxexportrequest you have to wrap the text and with " instead of {

That means the [This article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff601762%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) needs to be updated to change it away from:

`-ContentFilter {Received -lt '$Variable'}`

To:

```
-ContentFilter "Received -lt '$Variable'"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a solution to this problem, it was driving me mad!

I took bit and pieces from the mentioned article, [this article](https://www.mysysadmintips.com/windows/servers/282-exchanage-2010-the-provided-contentfilter-value-is-invalid) from mysysadmintips.com and [this article](http://occasionalutility.blogspot.com/2014/03/everyday-powershell-part-17-using-new.html?_sm_au_=iHV1qHS1LVTWF6Rn) from Occasional Utility.

I did some further research into New-PSSession and New-PSSessionOption.
Finally got it working using a PSSession and splatting.

No need to change the regional settings on your Exchange server.

```
$SessionOption = New-PSSessionOption -Culture 'en-US'
$PSSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "https://<ExchangeServer>/PowerShell/" -SessionOption $SessionOption

$DateRangeStart = ([datetime]::Today).Addmonths(-3) # 3 months from today
$DateRangeEnd = [datetime]::Now # Now :)

$ExportParam = @{
        Name = <RequestName>
        Mailbox = <Mailbox>
        ExcludeDumpster = $true
        FilePath = <ExportPath>
        ContentFilter = "((Received -le '"+$DateRangeEnd+"') -and (Received -ge '"+$DateRangeStart+"')) -or ((Sent -le '"+$DateRangeEnd +"') -and (Sent -ge '"+$DateRangeStart+"'))"
}

Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock {New-MailboxExportRequest @ExportParam}
```